# Javascript how to properly access associative array elements

Tags: javascript, associative-array

I am having a bit of difficulty understanding how to access elements from a 2 dimension associative array. For example, when I try using the "price" key from the first array, it returns as object Object. I am having a hard time returning the values that the keys are related to. I have tried without quotations also. Thanks for your time.

```
var houseData = Array(
    {
        "price": "$320, 000",
        "imgsrc": "./images/colonial.jpg",
        "description": "Colonial House, 3 bedrooms"
    },
    {
        "price": "$459, 999",
        "imgsrc": "./images/contemporary.jpg",
        "description": "Colonial House, 3 bedrooms"
    },
    {
        "price": "$179, 500",
        "imgsrc": "./images/cottage.jpg",
        "description": "Colonial House, 3 bedrooms"
    },
    {
        "price": "$210, 000",
        "imgsrc": "./images/ranch.jpg",
        "description": "Colonial House, 3 bedrooms"
    },
    {
        "price": "$159, 999",
        "imgsrc": "./images/townhouse.jpg",
        "description": "Colonial House, 3 bedrooms"
    });
```

Comment: `houseData[0].price` returns `[object Object]`? How are you *trying* to access the data?

Comment: I think you need to do a course on basic JavaScript (or programming in general).

Comment: There is no such thing as an associative array in JavaScript. It's an Object ;)

Comment: houseData[0].price or houseData[0]['price'] is what you are looking for (the former is preferred).

Comment: You say this is "a 2 dimension associative array", but it isn't. It is a simple 1-dimensional array (of objects). Also, by convention most JS programmers use [] to create an array, just as we write {} to create an object (just how you created the objects inside your example array).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, brackets in JS will create an object. With the Array function, you are creating a list of object. So as @Salehen Rahman said, you need to first access the object in the list by specifying an index :

```
var objectAtIndex0 = houseData[0];
```

and then access the data in the object:

```
var priceFromObjectAtIndex0 = objectAtIndex0.price;
```

or one-line:

```
var priceFromObjectAtIndex0 = houseData[0].price;
```